# Convert String with self-defined operators to XML format in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, recursion

1. Input is a String with key,val pair and operators
2. Operators support "AND", "OR", "()"
3. The order of the operation is from left to right, but "()" takes precedence
4. Output is a String with XML format

For example:

input01:

```
String input = "001,1399"
```

output01:

```
<ITEM  key="001"  val="1399" />
```

input02:

```
String input = "((((001,1399))))"
```

output02:

```
//Same as output01
```

input03:

```
String input = "001,1399 OR 002,1399"
```

output03:

```
<CONDITION rel="OR" >
    <ITEM  key="001"  val="1399" />
    <ITEM  key="002"  val="1399" />
</CONDITION>
```

input04:

```
String input = "001,1399 OR 002,1399 AND 011,1564 OR 011,1567"
```

output04:

```
<CONDITION  rel="OR" >
    <CONDITION  rel="AND" >
        <CONDITION rel="OR" >
            <ITEM  key="001"  val="1399" />
            <ITEM  key="002"  val="1399" />
        </CONDITION>
        <ITEM  key="011"  val="1564" />
    </CONDITION>
    <ITEM  key="011"  val="1567" />
</CONDITION>
```

input05:

```
String input = "001,1399 OR 002,1399 AND (011,1564 OR 011,1567)"
```

Output05:

```
<CONDITION  rel="AND" >
    <CONDITION rel="OR" >
        <ITEM  key="001"  val="1399" />
        <ITEM  key="002"  val="1399" />
    </CONDITION>
    <CONDITION  rel="OR" >
        <ITEM  key="011"  val="1564" />
        <ITEM  key="011"  val="1567" />
    </CONDITION>
</CONDITION>
```

Can someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: Hint: [ANTLR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)

Comment: 1) Parse the expression (e.g. by Antlr as suggested by Basil Bourque) and build a tree structure representing the input expression.
2) Modify the tree structure to eliminate uncessary nesting (expressed by redundant brackets in your example).
3) Traverse the (modified) tree and build the output string.